# Symfony error - Failed to write cache file

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I have inherited a Symphony site and I get the following error,

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Failed to write cache file "/var/www/html/app/cache/prod/classes.php".' in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ClassCollectionLoader.php:239
```

I did a `chmod -R 777 cache` but with no luck. The classes.php file does not exist.

Comment: php bin/console security:check, what shows you, refer http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#book-installation-permissions for use

Answer (score 0):

If you are linux user then you need to fire below listed command:

```
HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`

sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var

sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var
```

Comment: Then you need to first install ```acl``` using ```sudo apt-get install acl```